# Databinding ComboBox "SelectedItem" property has incorrect initial selection

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I'm working with the winforms ComboBox and have the following manual databinding:

```
ComboBox c = new ComboBox ()
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
    DisplayMember = "Name",
};

c.DataBindings.Add ("SelectedItem", item, "SelectedPrinter", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
c.DataSource = new List<Printer> (printers);
```

`Printer` is a value type (thus the `?` to make this `Nullable<Printer>` behind the scenes. Meanwhile, `Item` is a type that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and boils down to (it properly implements INotifyPropertyChanged for the SelectedPrinter property, I'm omitting here for brevity):

```
class Item
{
    Printer? SelectedPrinter { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, when I add this ComboBox to a form and show the form, the first printer from the list of available printers is automatically selected. I would like the combobox to respect *whatever* the initial SelectedPrinter property value is, whether it's null for no selection, or contains a printer selection of some sort.

I've attempted manually setting the `combobox.SelectedValue` both before and after the ComboBox is added to the control hierarchy, to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, the only problem you're having is that when the selected printer is null, it's auto-selecting the first printer in the list if the selected printer is null? That's expected behaviour as far as I can recall.

What you can do is check to see if the selected printer is null and then set the combobox's SelectedIndex to -1. Otherwise, you may have to create a null object and seed it into the datasource.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I eventually ended up doing. I added a custom combo box as described at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/a530f011-54d9-44d1-a585-145ea28ff370/ and then added a proper override of the Equals method and now it's finally working. Thanks!